# How to split cell of a grid into columns winforms devexpress

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, devexpress

I would like learn something.
I have a `GridControl` which has a `gridview` inside with some columns. And there's one column lets name "jobs". in my `DataList`(which i'm populating rows with) i have another list which will hold some infos about jobs and i want to show them in one column. But there's the problem. I want to split the cell of "jobs" . how can i do that?

the model and the list is like below:

```
//this is my job class
public class JobInfo{
   public string Name;
   public bool IsDone;
}

//this is my work class
public class Work{
   public string Company;
   public string Personel;
   public List<JobInfo> Jobs;
}
```

in my cs file I will hold a `List<Work>` object. I can bound it to grid view but i want to show job info like that cell contains 4 or 5 cells or how many jobs that list has.

I tried some paint to be as clear as much
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVAEx.jpg

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It's not possible with Grid Control and Vertical Grid without any work around. you can create columns dynamically for Jobs(n columns) and use BandedGridView which let you group these columns to display single column header.

Answer (score 0):

You can not have columns inside columns in a GridView.

How about just adding it into one cell like this?

```
private void gridView_CustomColumnDisplayText(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.CustomColumnDisplayTextEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Column.FieldName == "Jobs")
    {
        var jobs = e.Value as List<JobInfo>;
        e.DisplayText = jobs != null ? 
                        string.Join(" | ", jobs.Select(j => string.Format("Name: {0}, Is Done: {1}", j.Name, j.IsDone))) : 
                        string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Comment: i've tried and shown him and had argue with him :) thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do exactly what you need. But maybe it is an option to use a repositoryItem. You could use a popupcontaineredit. Then you build a popupcontainercontrol with a new Grid. If someone click a row or on the dropdown of your popupcontaineredit you can popup your popupcontainercontrol and populate the list of jobs in the uppoping grid.

I hope you understand what i mean.

regards.

Comment: i understand what you mean. actually that would be nice for me but not to my boss. anyway i've convinced him that is not possible without great effort and time. what i did is i've placed the columns dynamically(i mean inside columns. we've given up the base columns). thanks for helping btw :)